# json object - not getting output instead getting object.object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have written the below code but in the output i am getting object.object. Please can you tell me the issue and resolution

Code

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("success");
       
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=f97a52c4251d786439d16642a76845d3&q=london', function(data) {
         JSON.stringify(data);
         var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
      });
     
      $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
       
       
       alert("sucess");
       
    })
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Output :

[object Object]
[object Object]
stations
[object Object]
10000
[object Object]
[object Object]
1492455000
[object Object]
2643743
London
200

JSON returned from endpoint:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 804,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "overcast clouds",
      "icon": "04d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 283.31,
    "pressure": 1024,
    "humidity": 46,
    "temp_min": 282.15,
    "temp_max": 285.15
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 3.1,
    "deg": 340
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 92
  },
  "dt": 1492453200,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5091,
    "message": 0.0872,
    "country": "GB",
    "sunrise": 1492405121,
    "sunset": 1492455727
  },
  "id": 2643743,
  "name": "London",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: You are converting the values of the returned objects to strings. If they are strings already, numbers, booleans, etc. no problem, but objects get converted to `[object Object]`. Wrap `val` in a call to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I would suggest you learn debugging. If you are using chrome then chrome developer tool would tell you where the problem is. By the way, if val is a simple object you don't even need to do JSON.stringify. Doing something like val.name would do the job(assuming val object has name key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating this multidimensional JavaScript object as a flat array.

When you get an object, you have to iterate inside it like this.

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    if (typeof val == 'object') {
        $.each( val, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
        });
    }
    else {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
    }
});
```

And you are giving away your API key on the question. You may want to change it later on..

Answer (score 2):

First this line:

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

Does nothing, because you aren't assigning the result to anything. It doesn't mutate the original `data`.

Second, the `[object Object]` is the default behavior of calling `toString` on an object. And you have objects in your JSON. For example this guy:

```
"coord": {
    "lon": -0.13,
    "lat": 51.51
}
```

The value of the `coord` is an object with properties `lon` and `lat`. If you want to print those in some human readable format, you need to tell it how to do that.

The super quick and dirty way would be to do as @JaredSmith suggested in the comments, something like:

```
items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + JSON.stringify(val) + "</li>" );
```

Which gives you this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       alert("success");
       
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=f97a52c4251d786439d16642a76845d3&q=london', function(data) {
         JSON.stringify(data);
         var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + JSON.stringify(val) + "</li>" );
      });
     
      $( "<ul/>", {
        "class": "my-new-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
       
       
       alert("sucess");
       
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This is still ugly, from an end user point-of-view. But to fix that you need to actually decide how you want to format the data.

A slightly less ugly version might do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=f97a52c4251d786439d16642a76845d3&q=london', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      unwrapObject(items, key, val);
    });

    $("<ul/>", {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: items.join("")
    }).appendTo("body");
  });


  function unwrapObject(items, key, val) {
    if (typeof(val) === "object") {
      items.push("<li>" + key + "</li>");
      items.push("<ul>");
      for(var p in val) {
        unwrapObject(items, p, val[p]);
      }
      items.push("</ul>");
    } else {
      items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Here you can see how it looks if I'm logging it into the console. We got an regular Object :)

You have got a response which is an object, so you need to handle this object like this

`items.push( "<li id='" + JSON.stringify(key) + "'>" + JSON.stringify(val) + "</li>" );`